# One word for the type of smile which suggests "I’ve got you! Now you can’t escape!"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there one word for the type of smile which shows the following type of emotion:

> I’ve got you! Now you can’t escape!

For example, a detective smiles this way on finding an irrefutable piece of evidence that will convict a notorious criminal.

Comment: Usually that's called a "triumphant" smile or grin.

Comment: There's a smile that says all that?  Is there a frown that says, "The truth is, you could actually escape if you wanted to."?

Comment: Are we writing a novel?

Comment: @WarrenP No, I am not. But that doesn't mean I won't in the future ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right off the top of my head, I’d probably go with *triumphant*.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **smirk**. It means *to smile in a smug or self-satisfied manner*. It is often used pejoritively, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

If the bad guy was gloating while holding the detective in his clutches, then I'd probably call that a *sinister* smile.  But fortunately, in this case, it's the detective who has the upper hand, and he is flashing a *knowing* smile.

From [**Collins**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/knowing):

> **knowing** (*adj.*)
>   1. suggesting secret information or knowledge
>   2. wise, shrewd, or clever
>   3. deliberate; intentional

Answer (score 1):

There is the collocation *predatory smile*.